# Get only wild card value using regular expression

Tags: c#, .net

I want to extract only wild card tokens using regular expressions in dotnet (C#).

Like if I use pattern like `Book_*` (so it match directory wild card), it extract values what match with `*`.

For Example:

- For a string `"Book_1234"` and pattern `"Book_*"`
  I want to extract `"1234"`
- For a string `"Book_1234_ABC"` and pattern `"Book_*_*"`
  I should be able to extract 1234 and ABC

Comment: replacing * with \w+ does not work?

Answer (score 0):

This should do it : ([DEMO](http://ideone.com/a41abM))

```
string input = "Book_1234_ABC"; 

MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(input, @"_([A-Za-z0-9]*)");

foreach (Match m in matches) 
    if (m.Success)
        Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[1].Value);
```

Answer (score 0):

The approach to your scenario would be to

1. Get the List of strings which appears in between the wildcard (*).
2. Join the lists with regexp divider (|).
3. replace the regular expression with char which you do not expect in your string (i suppose space should be adequate here)
4. trim and then split the returned string by char you used in previous step which will return you the list of wildcard characters.

   ```
       var str = "Book_1234_ABC";
       var inputPattern = "Book_*_*";
       var patterns = inputPattern.Split('*');
       if (patterns.Last().Equals("")) 
           patterns = patterns.Take(patterns.Length - 1).ToArray();
       string expression = string.Join("|", patterns);
       var wildCards = Regex.Replace(str, expression, " ").Trim().Split(' ');
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I would first convert the '*' wildcard in an equivalent Regex, ie:

`*` becames `\w+` 
then I use this regex to extract the matches.

Answer (score 0):

When I run this code using your input strings:

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace SampleApplication
{
    public class Test
    {
        static Regex reg = new Regex(@"Book_([^_]+)_*(.*)");

        static void DoMatch(String value) {
            Console.WriteLine("Input: " + value);

            foreach (Match item in reg.Matches(value)) {
                for (int i = 0; i < item.Groups.Count; ++i) {
                    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Group: {0} = {1}", i, item.Groups[i].Value));
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine("\n");
        }

        static void Main(string[] args) {
            // For a string "Book_1234" and pattern "Book_*" I want to extract "1234"
            DoMatch("Book_1234");

            // For a string "Book_1234_ABC" and pattern "Book_*_*" I should be able to extract 1234 and ABC
            DoMatch("Book_1234_ABC");
        }
    }
}
```

I get this console output:

```
Input: Book_1234
Group: 0 = Book_1234
Group: 1 = 1234
Group: 2 = 

Input: Book_1234_ABC
Group: 0 = Book_1234_ABC
Group: 1 = 1234
Group: 2 = ABC
```